# Is there a 1-click method to do this 3-4 click task?

Tags: settings

I'm on a pay-as-you go scheme using an HTC desire with Android 2.3 installed. Right now, to activate my mobile internet (which I do only when I need to check email) needs me to go to `Settings > Wireless > tick 'Mobile Networks'`.

**Question:**

Is there a 1-click way of doing this? I probably will need to install an app that helps me do this I'm guessing?

*I spent several minutes looking for this over Google, but I suspect I didn't know what to search for*

Comment: Are you turning off the network totally?  Turning off data should be sufficient, and then onik's answer should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try searching for a data toggle widget on the market to add a one-click shortcut. For example, I found [Data Enabler Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.farproc.data.enabler) pretty easily.

Comment: Tried installing data enabler, wasn't what I was after as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

HTC desire already has a widget to switch off and on wifi, mobile network, bluetooth, sync and some other option. It's a 4x1 widget with 5 toggle buttons...

Comment: Thanks Axeman, are you referring to the widget with Wifi, Bluetooth, GPS, Update and Brightness on it? It doesn't have the mobile network bit as far as I can tell. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Mine has it. But there is also the single button widget for mobile network toggle... look at http://www.htc.com/uploadedImages/Common/HowTo/HTC_Tattoo/S_Mobile_Network_Widget.png ... graphics could change, but I've seen it on every HTC phone I used.

Comment: How do you get the widget though? The usual long press method doesn't get me any widgets remotely related to mobiles.

Comment: I suppose it should be "add/widget/settings/mobile network" (I use italian language on my HTC Desire)

Comment: Nope, I don't get Settings when I long press. But maybe that's because I'm using a different homescreen app. Will rollback to the old one and try again